# Clearcase: make baseline, but donot recommend, Can it cause error for others

Tags: clearcase

This is regarding, IBM Rational Clearcase Explorer application. If we deliver some files, and take the step of "make baseline". After that, if we don't do the "Recommend Baseline" step, will it cause problem for others trying to deliver to the same stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After that, if we don't do the "Recommend Baseline" step, will it cause problem for others trying to deliver to the same stream?

deliver, no. Rebase maybe, as ClearCase will rebase by default the recommended baseline of the parent (source) UCM stream.

But for delivering ([`cleartool deliver`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_deliver.htm)), you can deliver the baseline you want.
Since the deliver stream's recommended baseline is selected by default, that could also trip a user not double-checking the exact name of the auto-selected baseline.

Comment: Actually, I have seen a few such instances, where delivery step gives some error saying "error because some files couldn't be checked out...". And the reason apparently, is someone delivered and "make baseline" same files, but left it without "recommend" step. I wanted to make sure that that is the real cause. Couldn't find any link anywhere confirming my suspicion.

Comment: @shanti no, "recommended baseline" is just a marker.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, let me take some more time searching the cause of the error. I am getting error while delivering, and I am sure it is due to someone else having left the process of clearcase thing prematurely at some step.

Comment: I can't recall the exact error, but it was pretty close to- "Error while delivery. Some files couldn't be checked out to the stream". And I could see those files with red error symbol. Just that it didn't give any further explanation of error. Had got similar error earlier, and I vaguely remember that it was due to someone else having left the step midway (probably after "make baseline" step I think).

Comment: @shanti I don't think it is because of a recommended status. Generally, it is because the destination file is invisible, not selected and cannot be checked out.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me check out more on this. Tomorrow I should be able to conclude why it happened.

Comment: I had a look around and got the reason of the error I am getting. It is due to someone else having "delivered" same file as I am trying to deliver, but he hasn't completed the process by doing "make baseline" and "recommend baseline". It looks delivering a file, does a reserved check out and anyone else can't deliver the same file till the earlier delivery process is completed.http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21272142

Comment: I agree, but the recommended part is completely optional though.

Comment: hmmm ok, so it means that if the person just does "Make Baseline" step, the other person should be able to deliver then. Right?

Comment: Yes, because the deliver operation would be concluded, and all files checked in.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for pitching in with your help. I am not very familiar with clearcase, so was a bit confused

Comment: No problem. You can recommend a baseline at any time, long after a deliver.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommending a baseline will not prevent a subsequent deliver operation.

Please note that all deliver operations are merges, which can cause "merge creep" issues if you use deliver to push changes back into child streams. As a general rule, don't deliver to child streams.

If you get a deliver that says that some file's can't be checked out, it **usually** means someone else is delivering. Not knowing the checkout error message, I can't tell you that this **is** what is happening though.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have got the solution to the error through an ibm link posted in one of my earlier reply to anothet answer here. It was due to multiple delivery issue